# SQL Server index scans when there are more fields?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm having some trouble with an index, it seems to defy logic. I have several queries which all need fields from the same table; to that end, I created an index that will cover all of them. One of those queries had a seek predicate of the "PatientID" and returned the FirstName and LastName fields. Yet, the index which had just those fields (smallOne shown below) did a seek, whereas the index which was identical, aside for adding 2 more fields (both INTs) did a scan instead. Why would the larger index do a scan instead of a seek?

```
USE [Database Name goes here]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX smallOne
ON [Schema].[TableName] (PatientID])
INCLUDE ([FirstName],[LastName])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX largerOne
ON [Schema].[TableName] (PatientID])
INCLUDE ([FirstName],[LastName],XXXX,YYYY)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the only difference between the indices? Are their statistics equally fresh? What happens when you run the query with `with (forceseek(largerOne))`?

Comment: I literally copied/pasted them with the changes to the names as you see them here, no other changes are being used. As for your second suggestion, there are many queries which will utilize this index, kind of cumbersome to change all of them. Why would more fields switch to a scan instead?

Comment: `Why would more fields switch to a scan instead?` because the estimated cost is less.  The reason @GSerg asked you to try to force a seek is to see if it actually is cheaper to seek than scan.  It's not always the case.

Comment: I compared the performance of the two indices, and I found that largerOne was doing about 10% of the reads/scans (from IO statistics) as compared to shortOne; I forced a seek on the index, and it seeked, though used much more reads, similar numbers to the smallerOne index. Thanks so much!